# Python random digit letter and additional generator

Tags: python, random, generator

I would like to generate a random number string of N length with this code:

```
import random
import string

N=512
print ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(N))
```

What is missing is that I would like to add "special characters like e.g. "@,;:.§$%&/(!""
And I would like to output that to .txt file with a newline after for a example 10,15 signs.

Any help would be great.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
import string

allowable_gibberish = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
def gibberish_maker(gibberish=allowable_gibberish,n=512,new_line_every=15):
    str = ''.join(random.choice(gibberish) for x in range(n))
    return '\n'.join(str[i:i+new_line_every] for i in xrange(0, len(str), new_line_every))
```

Note: string.ascii_letters is the same as string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase.

Comment: Thx also a lot for this script! But here I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_punctuation'

Comment: Sorry, I was on a roll with the whole "ascii_" prefix. That doesn't belong in front of punctuation, it's just 'punctuation'.

Comment: COOL works I added: f = open('gibberish.txt', 'w')
f.write(gibberish_maker())
f.close()

Answer (score 5):

`string` module has a class for such special characters:

```
>>> print string.punctuation
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

To save generated string to file use something like:

```
N=512
chars_per_line = 15

s = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation) for i in xrange(N))

fh = open('filename', 'w')
try:
    fh.writelines([s[i:i+chars_per_line]
                   for i in range(0, N, chars_per_line)])
finally:
    fh.close()
```

Comment: cool thanks! And how about the output to file and newline? Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Python doesnt like "with". I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: with is new in Python 2.6. In Python 2.5, put `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of your file.

Comment: THX a lot! But now I get: ValueError: sample larger than population

Comment: The N in the 3rd line should be ``chars_per_line``

Comment: Big Thx! It works for printing all the 512 signs. But it does not go to a newline after 15 characters. Exchanging N with chars_per_line creates only one line with 15 Characters. I believe in the try part I also need a \n somewhere. Am I wrong?